# SPARC and x86 GCC different result of one C code

Tags: c, linux, gcc, solaris, sparc

One C code bring different result on “SPARC Solaris 5.9” and “Linux OpenSuse 12.1 i686 (x86)”.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char Cmd = '\x00';

  char tmp[2];
  char* TempBuff = &tmp;

  *(short*)TempBuff = (Cmd << 8) | 0x5;

  printf("Out: First byte:0x%02X, Second byte: 0x%02X\n", *(TempBuff), *(TempBuff+1) );

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling: gcc cshort.c –o cshort

On “Linux OpenSuse 12.1 i686 (x86)”:>  **Out: First byte:0x05, Second byte: 0x00**

On “SPARC Solaris 5.9”:>  **Out: First byte:0x00, Second byte: 0x05**

Why, why we received different outcome?

---

***Details of environment:***

*“SPARC Solaris 5.9”:*

uname –a: SunOS V245-1 5.9 Generic_118558-34 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V245.

psrinfo –v: The sparcv9 processor operates at 1504 MHz, and has a sparcv9 floating point processor.

gcc version 3.4.6

---

*“Linux OpenSuse 12.1 i686 (x86)”:*

uname –a: Linux linux-755z.site 3.1.10-1.19-desktop #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Feb 25 10:32:50 UTC 2013 (f0b13a3) i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

cat /proc/cpuinfo: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T8100  @ 2.10GHz

gcc version 4.6.2 (SUSE Linux)

---

Below attached disassembled code of  both versions.

[image: disassembled code of x86 versin]

---

[image: disassembled code of SPARC versin]

Comment: SPARC is big-endian, Intel is little-endian.

Comment: Joe> but C and gcc must be equalize low level difference of processor architectures, or?

Comment: Well, it is.  If you treat it as a short, you get the same value on both platforms.  It's when you are looking inside the abstraction, at the bytes that make up the short, where you are broken.  That becomes an application responsibility.

Comment: Not addressed anywhere yet, so:  `*(short*)TempBuff = (Cmd << 8) | 0x5;` is [a strict aliasing violation and invokes undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).  It's also extremely likely to generate a process-killing `SIGBUS` on SPARC systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you cast an 8 bit array type to short (16 bit) on a little endian platform, you'll get a different result than what you get on a big endian platform when doing the same.

The compiler can't help you with that, since that is just the nature of endianess...

Comment: The [wikipedia article on Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) has a fairly decent explanation.

Comment: *If you cast an 8 bit array type to short (16 bit) ...* You get a strict aliasing violation and undefined behavior on all platforms.

Comment: @Andrew Henle: might be true for C++, but I don't think so for C:  _A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting  pointer  is  not  correctly  aligned for  the  referenced  type,  the  behavior  isundefined._

Comment: @mfro And from your own quote:  "If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined"  The code `*(short*)TempBuff = (Cmd << 8) | 0x5;` does not ensure proper alignment, and by converting a `char *` address that doesn't refer to a the address of a `short` to a `short`, it's a strict aliasing violation even if the address does align properly.  Using a variable as something it's not is a strict aliasing violation, and that's exactly what the posted code does. Developers who grow up on x86 and its forgiving memory model learn some very bad habits.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, someone write abstruse and not safe code, I correct it:

```
//*(short*)TempBuff = (Cmd << 8) | 0x5;
TempBuff[0] = 0x5;
TempBuff[1] = Cmd;
```

Thank all for help.